# GetAdaptersAddresses Icon

Tags: c++, visual-studio

With `GetAdaptersAddresses()` you seem to be able to get everything about the adapter bar the icon used in:

```
Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections
```

does anyone know where to find the icon?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're asking for, but icons in windows are in dll files. The network icons are in

C:\Windows\System32\netcenter.dll

I'll explain you how i find them, just in case you want other icons.

1 - Go to ControlPanel->Network and Internet
2 - Then right click in the icon you want and select "Create shorcut"
[image]
3 - Now in Desktop, right click in the icon and open Properties
4 - Then click "Change icon..." and there you've got all icons in that dll
[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: No I know where windows keeps its stock icons but I'm looking to get the icon assigned to the adapter that may well be a stock item but more often than not is a custom icon supplied by the device manufacturer.

Comment: You got a description by alseether that Shows how to get the DLL. You can also create a shortcut at the adapters. Do you want to try this and describe why it failed?

Comment: A network adapter has no concept of how it is displayed in the Shell. Only the Shell knows that. So, whenever you want to mimic something that the Shell does, you have to query the Shell itself. In this case, you will have to use Shell interfaces to enumerate the Shell's Control Panel Network items until you find the one for your adapter, then query the Shell item for its icon.